# I get an error - may be from pagebackref

Tags: errors

I get an error as follows.

```
Package l3regex /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3regex.sty, line 42
 Warning: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3' instead on input line 42.
```

My line 42 is

```
\usepackage[
    pagebackref=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
    ]
    {hyperref}
    \renewcommand\backrefxxx[3]{%
    \hyperlink{page.#1}{$\uparrow$#1}%
}
```

Do you have any idea?

My sty file is

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{first}{
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\textit{Ajith Kularathna Aluvihare Gedara}}
\cfoot{}
}
\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\textit{Ajith Kularathna Aluvihare Gedara}}
\cfoot{}
}
\fancypagestyle{last}{
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\textit{Ajith Kularathna Aluvihare Gedara}}
\cfoot{}
}
\fancypagestyle{app}{
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{APPENDICES}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\textit{Ajith Kularathna Aluvihare Gedara}}
\cfoot{}
}
\raggedbottom %preventing spreading paras. 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\newcommand*\pkg[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\usepackage[
    pagebackref=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
    ]
    {hyperref}
    \renewcommand\backrefxxx[3]{%
    \hyperlink{page.#1}{$\uparrow$#1}%
}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.1cm}
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}



\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}
%\definecolor{lred}{RGB}{255,50,0}

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Validation of innovative binder solution for wooden circular designed products},
    pdfauthor={Ajith Kularathna Aluvihare Gedara},
    pdfsubject={Manufacturing Engineering},
    pdfkeywords={Wood adhesives, wood binders},
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,       
    colorlinks=true,            
    pdfstartview=Fit,           
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,    % this is the option you were looking for
    pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning,shadows,trees}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, text width=8em, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=8em, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=6em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} % table line thickness
\newcommand*{\hlt}[1]
{
\tikz[baseline]\node[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded corners, inner sep=0.3mm,anchor=base]{#1};
}

\newcommand*{\hlr}[1]
{
\tikz[baseline]\node[rectangle, fill=magenta, rounded corners, inner sep=0.3mm,anchor=base]{#1};
}

\newcommand*{\hlg}[1]
{
\tikz[baseline]\node[rectangle, fill=green, rounded corners, inner sep=0.3mm,anchor=base]{#1};
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc]
```

My main file is

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{packs}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{files/ttl_1}
\cleardoublepage
\input{files/ttl_2}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{first}
\chapter*{Dedication}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
To my son 
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\input{files/ack}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{equations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
    \newcommand{\myequations}[1]
{
    \addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par
}
\setlength{\cftequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}
\listofequations
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}
\cleardoublepage
\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\input{files/ab}
\cleardoublepage
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\input{files/abbri}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction to the thesis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction to the thesis}
\input{files/intro_to_thesis.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Literature review}
\input{chapters/Literature}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Methodology}
\input{chapters/Methodology}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Results and Discussion}
\input{chapters/Results}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{conclusion}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{last}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{app}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapters/app}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the actual error is almost certainly on line **41** that you have not shown, you are loading `l3regex` package, which as the message says, you should not.

Comment: @Ajith Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Actually, this error is coming only in overleaf v2. It is fine with overleaf v1. Thanks. I will go with v1 then.

Comment: @Ajith Fyi, your error is caused by loading `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}`.

Answer (score 4):

The line number in the warning belongs to the file `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3regex.sty` and *not* the main TeX file.

The package warning in the source code, lines 40--42:

```
\PackageWarning
  \old@liii@module@name{This package is obsolete ---
   use 'expl3' instead}
```

Thus, you have to check the `.log` file to find, where package `l3regex` is loaded. If it is your TeX file, then replace the package by `expl3` as suggested by the warning.

The problem is unrelated to page back references.